# Grails: can remoteField update multiple fields?

Tags: ajax, grails, groovy

Assume i have a book entity with an **isbn** field.
When entered a isbn number, i want 2 fields to be updated: title and author.

My controller looks like this:

```
def ajaxGetBook = {
        def book = Book.findByIsbn(params.isbn)
        if(book==null) book = new Book()
        render book as JSON
    }
```

So my call works, and i get a full JSON Book.
Now i would like to update 2 texfields by the update attribute

```
 <g:remoteField action="ajaxGetBook" update="title"  name="isbn" value="${bookInstance?.book?.isbn}" paramName="isbn"/>
```

Now the title field gets updated with the full book object, so that doesn't work.

*Is it possible to update field title with only the JSON book.title?*

*Is it possible to update more fields at once?*

I could `render book.title as JSON` but that works for only one field.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the g:remoteField tag is explicitly for one field, so you can't use it to update more than one. So, you're left with 2 easy choices:

1. Use 2 g:remoteField calls... this isn't a bad option, as they would happen in near parallel, as they are Async calls.
2. Roll your own Ajax.  use g:remoteFunction instead, and have the JS function that you place in the "success" attribute take your book, and update the appropriate HTML fields.